# Array.push is pushing only last object in the array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

**First i set ids as an object**

```
attribute.map((item, index) => {
                    setIds({ ...ids, [index]: item.id })
                })
```

*then i try to push it in an array, but it is only pushing last object*

```
let idsArr = []
Object.keys(ids).map(key => {
            idsArr.push(ids[key])
        })
```

Comment: `map` returns a new array after iterating over the elements so you should be doing that first, and _then_ updating the state, not updating the state on every iteration.

Comment: Please do not use `.map()` for simple array iteration. Use `.forEach()` or a normal loop to do that.

Comment: @VLAZ  .foreach() workks fine but when i push it in an array, it returns only last object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

You are enqueueing a bunch of React state updates inside a loop, using a normal update, and as each update is processed by React it uses the ***same***  value of `ids` from the render cycle they were all enqueued in. In other words, each update stomps the previous one and the last state update wins. This is the state value you see on the subsequent render cycle.

## Solutions

Use functional state updates to enqueue each update and have each update from the previous state instead of the state from the callback closure.

Example:

```
attribute.forEach((item, index) => {
  setIds(ids => ({
    ...ids,
    [index]: item.id,
  }))
});
```

With the correctly updated `ids` array state, you should be able to iterate and push values into the other array:

```
const idsArr = [];
Object.keys(ids).map(key => {
  idsArr.push(ids[key]);
});
```

Or just get the array of values directly:

```
const idsArr = Object.values(ids);
```

Answer (score 2):

one proposal can be to push the map result in array

```
idsArr.push(...Object.keys(ids).map(key => ids[key]));
```

Moreover when you set the id if you don't return nothing the map method should not be used.

A loop like foreach is a better choice

map method is used to get a "transformed" array

```
  attribute.forEach((item, index) => {
       setIds({ ...ids, [index]: item.id })
  })
```

```js
let idsArr = [];

let ids = {
  'test': 1,
  'test2': 2
};
idsArr.push(...Object.keys(ids).map(key => ids[key]));

console.log(idsArr);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but `idsArr.push(...Object.keys(ids).map(key => ids[key]));` is only returning last object

Comment: I create a snippet to show the expected result you have the two elements (in my sample 1 and 2)  in ids